# What is the correct path for user uploads in Heroku?

Tags: python, html, flask, heroku

As part of the 100 Days of Python course, I built a Flask website that extracts and displays the most used colors from a user-uploaded image, which is saved into app.config["UPLOAD_FOLDER"] = "static/user-img/". The project works fine locally, but when attempting to use it via deployment on Heroku, I am getting a FileNotFound error. I tried restructuring the upload folder to use an absolute path of "D:/blah/blah/blah/project_file/static/user-img/", but that returned the same FileNotFound error. Not sure where to go from here, so any help would be greatly appreciated. This is not an issue about Heroku using ephemeral file data; I don't need the image files stored for more than a few minutes, just long enough so that the function can extract the color data from the image. Changing the upload path from relative to absolute also returned the same error.

My project code is:

```
from colorthief import ColorThief
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import os
from datetime import datetime

ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = [".png", ".jpg", ".jpeg"]

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = os.environ.get("flask_key")
app.config["UPLOAD_FOLDER"] = "static/user-img/"
Bootstrap(app)

def process_colors(filename):
    file = ColorThief(filename)
    palette = file.get_palette(color_count=10)
    return palette

def allowed_file(filename):
    file = filename.split(".")[1]
    extension = f".{file}"
    if extension in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS:
        return True

@app.context_processor
def inject_year():
    year = datetime.now().year
    return dict(year=year)

@app.route("/")
def home():
    error = ""
    return render_template("index.html", error=error)

@app.route("/colors", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def colors():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files["file"]
        if file.filename != "" and allowed_file(file.filename):
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config["UPLOAD_FOLDER"], secure_filename(file.filename)))
            filename = f"{app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']}{file.filename}"
            top_ten_colors = process_colors(filename)
            return render_template("colors.html", filename=filename, colors=top_ten_colors)
        else:
            error = "Not a valid format. Please upload a .jpg, .jpeg, or .png file."
            return render_template("index.html", error=error)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And the error log is:

```
2022-03-23T10:09:22.219087+00:00 app[web.1]:     rv = self.dispatch_request()
2022-03-23T10:09:22.219087+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1502, in dispatch_request
2022-03-23T10:09:22.219088+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
2022-03-23T10:09:22.219088+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/main.py", line 41, in colors
2022-03-23T10:09:22.219089+00:00 app[web.1]:     file.save(os.path.join(app.config["UPLOAD_FOLDER"], secure_filename(file.filename)))
2022-03-23T10:09:22.219089+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/werkzeug/datastructures.py", line 3021, in save
2022-03-23T10:09:22.219090+00:00 app[web.1]:     dst = open(dst, "wb")
2022-03-23T10:09:22.219090+00:00 app[web.1]: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'static/user-img/20190216_131131.jpg'
2022-03-23T10:09:22.220755+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/colors?filename=" host=the-color-extractor.herokuapp.com request_id=ca81c495-554e-4e9b-9621-7365f926f812 fwd="153.254.152.14" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=10705ms status=500 bytes=463 protocol=https
2022-03-23T10:09:22.221055+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.29.122 - - [23/Mar/2022:10:09:22 +0000] "POST /colors?filename= HTTP/1.1" 500 290 "https://the-color-extractor.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.82 Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: Assuming you want those images for more than a day, there isn't one :-). Heroku's filesystem is ephemeral, so any uploads saved to the local filesystem will be lost frequently. Use something like Amazon S3, Azure Blob Storage, or Cloudinary instead.

Comment: (Note that the `FileNotFoundError` you're getting now isn't due to the ephemeral filesystem. I suggest you provide an absolute path, e.g. something starting with `/tmp`. But as soon as you get that working you'll run into the ephemeral filesystem issue.)

Comment: No, I don't need them to be saved for any long period of time, just long enough to run the function. I tried using an absolute file path like D:/blah/blah/blah/project_file/static/user-img/, but that gave me the same FileNotFoundError.

Comment: Well it won't start with `D:/`. This is a Linux system, not a Windows system. Again, try `/tmp/`.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research, I've found the answer in another Stack Overflow post.

[Flask uploading image FileNotFoundError:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66854255/18382452)

As the linked answer shows, you need to have some sort of placeholder file in the designated image upload folder in order for Heroku to recognize it and know to pull the saved image from that folder. So I added a .keep file to the upload folder, updated the Github repository, and once Heroku updated and saw that file in the upload folder, it was able to pull any subsequent images I saved to that folder.